# Vim remap text selection/copy/cut/paste to GUI editor standard (Ctrl+a, Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v etc)

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

Is it possible in Vim to

- Select text with Ctrl+A and Shift (+ Ctrl) + Arrows/Home/End
- Copy the selection to the system clipboard with Ctrl+c
- Cut the selection with to te system clipboard with Ctrl+x
- Paste the system clipboard contents with Ctrl+v
  like you can in most GUI text editors?

At the moment I have to  press
`Esc -> v -> arrows etc -> "*y -> "*p -> i`
just to select, copy and paste some text.
I would really love to get the standard GUI text editor keyboard bindings in vim.

Comment: Try [mswin.vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html#mswin.vim)